# How to monitor the state of the .Net Thread Pool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

Is it possible to find out the state of threads in the threadpool? Our application is sometimes using a lot of threads and these are mostly down to calls to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. However when the application isn't really doing much the thread count never decreases. I would have thought eventually these threads would be stopped.

Reading around I believe they should enter a suspended state when they have completed all tasks then if not reused eventually wake up and be terminated.

The application is using the .Net Compact Framework v2. It could be the threads are getting stuck, however when I pause the application in visual studio the threads window only displays around 7-8 threads. The remote process viewer bundled with v2005 states the process is using in excess of 40 threads. I can only assume it is just thread pool threads sat waiting to be used.

What approach can be used to test that the work in the ThreadPool is being completed and threads are being released back into the pool?

**EDIT 1**

[image: Thread Pool]

This is taken from the .NET Compact Framework Remote Performance Monitor and the thread pool thread count is at 25. However like i said in visual studio itself there certainly isn't 25 threads, only about 7 or 8.

Comment: You don't have to help the ThreadPool. You do have to make sure your tasks are short and are terminating.

Comment: `ThreadPool` will add threads when required and it will destroy them when it thinks it is no more needed. So you don't really need to bother about it.

Comment: I see you're asking *Is it possible to find out the state of threads in the threadpool?* what decision you're trying to make if you can get that information?

Comment: That is basically what i am trying to find out, are my tasks terminating? They appear not to be given the thread count never decreasing. However as I stated the threads in visual studio only show a fraction of them.

Comment: If you don't see those threads back in the debugger's Threads window then it is *not* the ThreadPool.  The operating system and whatever unmanaged components you use create them as well.  If they never execute managed code then they won't show up in the debugger window.  You need to use an unmanaged debugger to see them.

Comment: AFAIK (from Daniel Moth site) ThreadPool does not use Threads but one-shot timers to start threads. If this is tru, you would not see thread counting for ThreadPool 'threads'. As there is no API to check the state of the ThreadPool threads you have to implement your own 'state' using the object you can use with QueueUserWorkItem.